# How to add different values in list of tuples in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to add values in a dictionary having list of tuples but the key is same.

I am doing like this

```
public struct MyStruct { public List> list1; }
public static Dictionary<long, MyStruct> myDictionary = new  
                                              Dictionary<long, MyStruct>();
funct()
{
    if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
         myDictionary[key]= new MyStruct { list1 = s.list1 };
    } // this block is been called from another function
}
```

But as I am using new keyword every time the value coming is getting overwrite. but I want to append for which I am not getting another way. Please suggest me another way.. as I searched all over net but none solves my problem.

Comment: There can be only one value per key. If you want multiple you have to set the value as a list or other container

Comment: you can't have have multiple same keys for dictionary mate

Comment: Please check I have edited my post... @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen.. My value type in dictionary is a structure...and the key type is long...so for every key there are some records..that's why I took structure..

Comment: @inan...My value type in dictionary is a structure...and the key type is long...so for every key there are some records..that's why I took structure

Comment: Well yes, the value will be overwritten... you're overwriting it. That's what the dictionary indexer does. It's not clear what else you'd expect. Please post a [mcve] including desired results. Also, it looks like you've got a mutable value type at the moment - that's generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `new` keyword everytime, you can check for null, then add values to the list inside of your structure:

```
funct(){
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
         if(myDictionary[key].list1 != null) 
              myDictionary[key].list1.AddRange(s.list1);
         else myDictionary[key].list1 = new MyStruct { list1 = s.list1 };

    } // this block is been called from another function
}
```

This way if you already have values inside the list in the structure from the dictionary the new values will b added at the list too. If you do't have any value and the list is simply `null`, the program will act as by now and make a new list.

Comment: if(myDictionary[key]!=null)  ... it is giving error that.. operator != cannot be applied to operands of type 'Program.MyStruct' and '<null>'

Comment: @sakshi you can recheck now

Comment: It worked I didn't added if(myDictionary[key]!=null)... but the second line..and worked..

Comment: just one more query... actually I am using StreamReader.ReadlLine() to read every line...which are nothing but different values that I am storing in various structure elements...Is there any other method other than StreamReader.ReadLine() to go line by line in the text file and then read values and assign them to structures elements...

Comment: @sakshi yes [File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it reads reads all lines of the file into a string array...so then using array do i need to put the values into structure elements...is readallLines() memory efficient and also more quicker than readline()...

Comment: @sakshi you can post another question on that topic, but this indeed is more efficient than reading line by line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a value to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, first you need to check if the key already exists because keys should be unique, if the key doesn't exist you can set a value, otherwise if the key already exists then you get the value using that key and update it. Check the below example I hope it will help you understand how it works. You can execute the below example [here](http://rextester.com/STXMT55558)

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<long, MyStruct> myDictionary = new Dictionary<long, MyStruct>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myDictionary.Add(1, new MyStruct { Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2} });
            Add(1, 3);

            // printing out the values
            foreach(KeyValuePair<long, MyStruct> number in myDictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}", number.Key);
                Console.WriteLine("Values:");
                for(var i = 0; i < number.Value.Numbers.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(number.Value.Numbers[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Add(long key, int number)
        {
            if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var myStruct = myDictionary[key];
                if (myStruct.Numbers != null)
                {
                    myStruct.Numbers.Add(number);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myDictionary[key] = new MyStruct { Numbers = new List<int> { number }};
            }
        }
    }

    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public List<int> Numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: just one more query... actually I am using StreamReader.ReadlLine() to read every line...which are nothing but different values that I am storing in various structure elements...Is there any other method other than StreamReader.ReadLine() to go line by line in the text file and then read values and assign them to structures elements.

Comment: so what I am doing is like this :

Comment: s.name = sr.ReadLine();s.FRC = short.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
                        s.PJ = short.Parse(sr.ReadLine());